# Nested menu using parent id in knockoutJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js

I am try to create nested menu using given json data by the client.

Data :

```
var serverData = [
      {
        Id: "menuColorSearch",
        Text: "Color search"
      },
      {
        Id: "menuAncillaryProductMix",
        Text: "Ancillary product mix"
      },
      {
        Id: "menuDocuments",
        Text: "Documents"
      },
      {
        Id: "menuColorInfo",
        ParentId: "menuDocuments",
        Text: "Color info"
      },
      {
        Id: "menuReports",
        ParentId: "menuDocuments",
        Text: "Reports"
      },
      {
        Id: "menuMaintenance",
        Text: "Maintenance"
      },
      {
        Id: "menuPriceManagement",
        ParentId: "menuMaintenance",
        Text: "Price management"
      }
    ];
```

I am trying like this :

```
var Menu = function(dept, all) {
    var self = this;
    this.id = dept.Id;
    this.name = ko.observable(dept.Text);
    this.parentId = dept.ParentId;
    this.children = ko.observableArray();

    ko.utils.arrayForEach(all || [], function(menu) {

        if(menu.ParentId){
            if (menu.ParentId === self.id) {
                self.children.push(new Menu(menu, all));
            }
        }else{
            new Menu(menu, all)
        }
    });
};

var ViewModel = function(data) {
    this.root = new Menu(data[0], data);
};


$(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(serverData));
});
```

Templates :

```
<div data-bind="with: root">
    <ul data-bind="template: 'deptTmpl'">
    </ul>
</div>

<script id="deptTmpl" type="text/html">
    <li>
        <a data-bind="text: name"></a>
        <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'deptTmpl', foreach: children }">
        </ul>
    </li>
</script>
```

problem is that its only work when 2nd and 3rd object has parent ID. i am trying something like it should make nested menu according to given json data. so id there is no parent id on object it should add on root. and if object has parent id it should add according to parent id.

Please help me to correct my code or guide me if these is another way to do this in KnockoutJS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you http://jsfiddle.net/MCNK8/3/, the main idea is to rebuild main data array, by placing child inside parent

HTML

```
<script id="nodeTempl" type="text/html">
    <li>
        <a data-bind="text: Text"></a>
        <ul data-bind="template: {name: nodeTemplate, foreach: children }"></ul>
    </li>
</script>

<script id="nodeLeafTempl" type="text/html">
    <li>
        <a data-bind="text: Text"></a>
    </li>
</script>

<ul data-bind="template: {name: nodeTemplate, foreach: children }"></ul>
```

Javascript (@see fiddle)

```
var serverData = [
      {
        Id: "menuColorSearch",
        Text: "Color search"
      },
      {
        Id: "menuAncillaryProductMix",
          ParentId: 'menuColorSearch',
        Text: "Ancillary product mix"
      },
      {
        Id: "menuDocuments",
        Text: "Documents"
      },
      {
        Id: "menuColorInfo",
        ParentId: "menuReports",
        Text: "Color info"
      },
      {
        Id: "menuReports",
        ParentId: "menuDocuments",
        Text: "Reports"
      },
      {
        Id: "menuMaintenance",
          ParentId: 'menuReports',
        Text: "Maintenance"
      },
      {
        Id: "menuPriceManagement",
        ParentId: "menuMaintenance",
        Text: "Price management"
      }
    ];



function getNestedMenu(index, all) {
    var root = all[index];

    if(!root){
        return all;
    }

    if(!all[index].children){
        all[index].children = [];
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < all.length; i++){
        //<infinity nesting?>

        //put children inside it's parent
        if(all[index].Id == all[i].ParentId){
            all[index].children.push(all[i]);
            all[i].used = true;
        }

        //this is needed for each item, to determine which template to use        
        all[index].nodeTemplate = function(node) {
            return node.children.length > 0 ? 'nodeTempl' : 'nodeLeafTempl';
        }
        //</infinity nesting?>
    }

    return getNestedMenu(++index, all);
};

function getModel(data) {
    var items = getNestedMenu(0, data);

    //<remove duplicates, for infinity nesting only>   
    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
        if(items[i].used){
            items.splice(i, 1);
            i--;
        }
    }
    //</remove duplicates, for infinity nesting only>
    //<build root item>
    var model = {};
    model.children     = ko.observableArray(items);
    model.nodeTemplate = function(node) {
        return node.children.length > 0 ? 'nodeTempl' : 'nodeLeafTempl';
    }
    //</build root item>
    console.log(items);
    return model;
};


(function() {
    //new ViewModel(serverData);
    ko.applyBindings(getModel(serverData));
})();
```

Comment: it is for 1 level nesting only! can we extend this with 2 level ? and how ?

Comment: thank you very much for help me. currently i need only three levels and its working awesome :)